# How to write plugin that makes you embed code to wordpress pages?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a simple plugin, that should simply run a code on a page, where I add the [pluginname] block. I saw most plugins are working this way, but I can't find any help regarding this. (I'm not a professional, just doing it for fun)

For example:

I have this code `echo 'I love my life!';`

And I want to run this on the 'everalone' page, by adding `[lovemylife]`.

Can someone direct me to a page, that shows how to do this.

Comment: There are several plugins that already do that, PHP code to shortcodes. Check this one out https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js-php/.

Comment: I know about those, but I want to make it for practise.

Comment: Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple tutorial on how to create a WordPress plugin ["Creating A WordPress Plugin Is Easier Than You Think"](https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/creating-wordpress-plugin-easier-think/).

You can have a code like this inside your plugin that registers shortcodes and run your PHP code.

```php
// function that runs when shortcode is called
function custom_php($atts = [], $content = null, $tag = '') {
  return 'I love my life!';
} 

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('my_php', 'custom_php');
```

And now, after you enable the plugin, you can use the shortcode like this:

```
[my_php]
```

Make sure you have PHP `eval` function enabled before you try this. Many host providers disable such functions for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising, but I think this is not what I meant. Mine sounds easier. The code that runs is static. And the shortcode would be just this: [my_php], whithout the code.

Comment: You can't just `echo` inside wordpress code. That just does not work like this. Each shortcode function has to return a value. To do that, you just `return 'I love my life1';` inside `custom_php` function and then use `[my_php]` shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in functions.php

```
function lovemylife_shortcode(){
    $mystring = "I love my life!";
  return $mystring;
}

add_shortcode( 'lovemylife', 'lovemylife_shortcode' );
```

Now you can add below this code in any pages or post to display I love my life!.

```
[lovemylife]
```